# How to hide a PyQt application's icon from Mac OS X dock

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, dock

How do I make a [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) application (with which the user interacts solely via [the system tray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893984/pyqt-show-menu-in-a-system-tray-application) (in the Menu Bar)) hide itself from the Mac OS X dock?

Comment: @Matt upper right hand corner, where the wireless icon is.

Comment: Fair enough, @Rafe. It's typically called the Menu bar, but I can see how it's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

This is what you are looking for: http://uselessthingies.wordpress.com/2008/05/18/an-app-without-dock-icon-and-menu-bar/

tl;dr: Package(py2app/pyinstaller(recommended)) your app; in your app's Info.plist add `<key>LSUIElement</key><string>1</string>`.

Answer (score 2):

If use py2app to package your application. Set plist option like this:

```
OPTIONS = {
              ...
              'plist': {'LSUIElement': True},
              ...
          }
```