# Dock context menu for a PyQt application

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, contextmenu, dock

*Although similar, this is not [PyQt: Show menu in a system tray application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893984/pyqt-show-menu-in-a-system-tray-application).*

How do I configure the context menu for the dock icon in my PyQt application? For eg., Google Chrome's has two entries "New Window" and "New Incognito Window" besides the window titles in the dock context menu.